# Query data count column data SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

I have table people and I want result only `Departement`.

I have a more than 2 **Engineer** level.

I'm try query like this

```
SELECT
    Department, Level
FROM
    people 
WHERE 
    Level = 'Engineer' 
HAVING 
    (Level = 'Engineer' > 2)
```

but not result, help me thanks

Comment: It can't be `mySql` and `SQL-Server` at the same time, please tag the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(Level) > 2`. The query will be:

```
SELECT Department
FROM people 
WHERE Level = 'Engineer' 
GROUP BY Department
HAVING COUNT(Level) > 2
```